# Знак препинания в БСП со значением дополнения или причины

Tags: пунктуация, бсп

Какой знак препинания ставится в бессоюзном сложном предложении со значением причины или дополнения, если перед второй частью не обрывается?

Answer (score 1):

[Двоеточие в БСП ставится:](https://foxford.ru/wiki/russkiy-yazyk/znaki-prepinaniya-v-bessoyuznom-slozhnom-predlozhenii)

> ...Если вторая часть указывает основание или причину того, о чем
> говорится в первой части (в данном случае возможна подстановка союзов
> так как, потому что). Например: *Я глядел в огонь и боялся поднять
> голову: казалось, кто-то смотрит на меня из темноты* (Коваль).

Иные случаи с примерами - см. [**источник**](https://foxford.ru/wiki/russkiy-yazyk/znaki-prepinaniya-v-bessoyuznom-slozhnom-predlozhenii) (Знаки препинания в бессоюзном сложном предложении).